# Excel combining INDEX and MATCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a sheet with the following data:

```
  A         B
1 Raisa     A
2 Mellissa  A
3 Emma      A
4 Slyvia    B
5 Salina    C
6 Beula     A
7 Apolonia  F
```

And I would like to list all people with A's, like this:

```
Raisa
Mellissa
Emma
Beula
```

I currently use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A7;MATCH("A";B1:B7;0))
```

Which has the output

```
Raisa
```

How do I alter the formula so the following cells each show the 'next match'?

Comment: Similar question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096573/excel-return-values-from-multiple-matching-rows

Answer (score 5):

You can use this formula in D2

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$7;SMALL(IF(B$1:B$7="A";ROW(B$1:B$7)-ROW(B$1)+1);ROWS(D$2:D2)));"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

I used ; as separators because that's the style used in the question

Comment: +1, the route I chose not to take.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no duplicates in your data, keep on using your formula in the first cell (I'll assume `E1`, then use the following to copy down:

`=INDEX(offset($A$1:$A$7;MATCH(E1;$A$1:$A$7;0);0;;);MATCH("A";offset($A$1:$A$7;MATCH(E1;$A$1:$A$7;0);1;;);0))`

Of course, a filter could make your life easier.

Comment: Your formula has multiple issues: 1) it should most likely be `MATCH(E1;$B$1:$B$7` not `...$A...`. 2) replace `;` with `,` (international standard) 3) The formula will always return the second item. You probably omitted something!

Comment: nutsch's formula work's OK for me, Peter - once valid returns run out you get #N/A but that can be eliminated with ISERROR as per my answer.....or yours

Comment: @PeterAlbert: 1)it should only be $B if I didn't offset the column, 2)the question is working on French or other regional settings with semi-columns, so I stuck with that presentation.

Comment: My bad! I oversaw the parameter 1 in the OFFSET. +1

Answer (score 2):

Similar to nutsch's answer, try this formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$7,0),0),MATCH($E$1,OFFSET($B$1:$B$7,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$7,0),0),0)),"")
```

This assumes that you use your formula `=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH($E$1,B1:B7,0))` in `C1` - and store the value to look for (i.e. `A`) in cell `E1`.

(Note: replace the `,` with `;` according to your local settings)